# How should i organize mysql.connector in project

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, organizer

I'm trying to organize MySQL.connector functions in my project, and I'm currently using a separated .py file in which I created a Mysql class and create a bunch of functions. the main question is, is it right? how should I do it?

```py
import mysql.connector


class Mysql:
    def __init__(self, host='localhost', user='root', pwd='', db=''):
        self.host = host
        self._user = user
        self._pwd = pwd
        self.db = db

    def open(self):
        try:
            self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=self.host, user=self._user, passwd=self._pwd, database=self.db)
        except:
            print("could not connect to server")
        else:
            print("connected successfully")
            self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()

    def select(self, con, tab, num, *args):
        self.mycursor.execute(f"select {con} from {tab} {' '.join(args)}")
        if num == 0:
            val = self.mycursor.fetchall()
        else:
            val = self.mycursor.fetchmany(num)
        self.mycursor.close()
        self.mydb.close()
        return val

    def delete(self, con, tab, id):
        self.mycursor.execute(f"delete from {tab} where id = {id}")
        self.mycursor.close()
        self.mydb.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = Mysql('localhost', 'my_user', 'mypass', 'wine')
    db.open()
    val = db.select('*', 'wine_eval', 1, "order by id")
    print(val)
    db.open()
    val = db.select('*', 'wine_eval', 1, "order by id")
    print(val)
```

Comment: Usually you'll want your structure to focus on your models - i.e. not by abstracting `select` or `delete` etc. Your examples are far less readable than just sending plain SQL into the function, and you'll want to use placeholders for those statements to make use of properly escaped arguments

Comment: its because ill be using in a UI application, still wrong?, and how about using a class structure?